# C without stdio, what is possible?

Tags: c, stdio, standard-library, bootloader, osdev

I've been interested in programming an operating system for some time.  Delving through a few different sites, I've come across an interesting concept (to paraphrase): if you start writing your bootloader with #include, you've already made a fatal mistake.

I've gone through K&R, and the entire book includes it throughout each lesson.  Having used it throughout learning C, I don't know what I've learned that uses stdio and what doesn't.  What can you do in C without stdio?

Comment: No `#include` meaning a bootloader shouldn't use any functions from the C standard library? Are you supposed to roll your own instead? I'd argue that doing that would be a sure way to make your bootloader buggy.

Comment: 'stdio' - did you mean 'C runtime library'?

Comment: @Praetorian - I believe the problem is that many of the functions in stdio are implemented in terms of system-calls to the OS.  Any such function will self-destruct if called in an environment like a bootloader in which there is no OS to provide a system-call API to invoke.  Either the bootloader must provide this API itself, or it must avoid calling any such functions until after it has loaded an OS that does.  So in that sense, yes, you are supposed to roll your own if you require them.

Comment: @aroth, yes, but there are many libraries suitable for embedded environments (i.e. no OS). See uclibc and newlib for the leading open-source candidates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999) recognizes two types of implementation (§4 Conformance, ¶6):

- Freestanding - where the implementation (compiler plus library) only provides seven headers:

  ```
  <float.h>
  <iso646.h>
  <limits.h>
  <stdarg.h>
  <stdbool.h>
  <stddef.h>
  <stdint.h>
  ```

  These provide basic facilities for the language and declare no functions (the facilities in `<stdarg.h>` are explicitly defined as macros in the standard).  Note that it does not include complex numbers.
- Hosted - where the implementation provides the complete library defined by the standard.

The whole point of a freestanding implementation is to allow you to write any code you need unencumbered by the standard library in general, and the standard I/O functions specifically.  The downside is that you not only can but must provide those functions - or make use of alternatives provided by the implementation.  Note that in a freestanding implementation, the entry point for the program need not be called `main`.

What you are seeking is a freestanding implementation - or to use the freestanding portion of a hosted implementation.  You will use headers (unless you're insane), but they probably won't be the standard C library headers other than those listed for use with a freestanding implementation.

Comment: In practice, you are most likely to get a full implementation of the C standard library (not the minimal subset defined for freestanding environments) with various hooks defined to implement the required low-level functionality. This allows you to implement any subset of the standard library you need.

Comment: This isn't really accurate, those headers are the necessary minimum for a freestanding compiler to implement. In reality, most freestanding compilers will implement the whole ISO C. Where you get in trouble is when you take a compiler for a hosted system and try to write programs for a freestanding system, as there might be API calls inside the libraries.

Answer (score 1):

`stdio` stands for Standard Input/Output. As the name said, it contains things related to standard IO. The [Wikipedia article of stdio.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdio.h) lists the contents of stdio.h. You will need stdio.h if you use them. And you can check the [man page of stdio.h](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/stdio/) too for further details.

And for the OS part, writing an OS is much more than simple programming, even if it is an academic one. Before jumping to that you should learn data structures, algorithms, OS theories and much more. [The Design of the UNIX Operating System](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132017997) is a very good book to learn OS. [Nachos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Another_Completely_Heuristic_Operating_System) is an academic OS simulation program. You can check that too. And if you are fanatic about OS, then you should read the autobiography of Linus Torvalds [Just for Fun](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0066620724). Well, it's not a technical book, but you will get a feeling what it means writing an OS.

Comment: Definitely going to pick up the book, thank you for the feedback as well.

Answer (score 1):

Any bootloader will almost certainly have #include directives, unless it is poorly designed. I don't know where you got that quote, but perhaps you misunderstood it. A bootloader will invariably start with a piece of pure assembly code for the initial low-level processor initialization and to initialize the C runtime environment. This code is simply not possible to write in C. But the rest of the code can be as complex as needed, within the restrictions of the environment (memory, etc).

stdio is simply a set of file streams connected to some kind of device which can receive input and output. You can implement stdin, stdout, stderr or any subset of them. You also may implement a filesystem for which you can open arbitrary file streams. In a modern OS, this ends up connected to some kind of terminal typically, which involves quite a bit of layers in-between because it's a virtual terminal that shows up on your monitor and thus requires a graphics driver and so forth. On a primitive embedded system, stdio might be connected to a serial port, or an LED display.

stdio is implemented with the `read()` and `write()` functions. If these are not implemented, you simply can't use the stdio functions like `printf()`, `fprintf()`, `fgets()`, etc. That doesn't mean you can't write to your graphics display, serial port or whatever else. It just means you don't have a standard facility to do so and will need to call custom functions.

To answer your question: you can do anything in C without stdio. It's all written in C anyway, you're just losing some common functionality implemented in any C standard library.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers about minimal C environments are good, but here's another more abstract angle.

The C standard defines two kinds of "observable side-effects", which basically means things your program does that cannot be optimized away or otherwise modified by the compiler. These are firstly calls to I/O functions, and secondly reads and writes of `volatile` objects.

If you don't have access to `stdio` or other parts of your C implementation that rely on the presence of the OS, you can't use I/O functions. That leaves reads and writes to `volatile` objects as the only things that your program will actually "do". In practice, you may or may not have to actually mark everything `volatile`, since your C implementation probably provides guarantees beyond the standard. If there's a CPU instruction that makes a beep noise, your compiler will treat that (and inline assembly in general) like an I/O function even though it's not really a function, and so on.

In other words, you will have to use low-level hardware access to achieve whatever it is your bootloader is supposed to achieve (which amounts to: display a message on screen, establish some resources that the OS needs in order to run, load it and run it). This access is of course entirely implementation-dependent - hardware vendors might provide libraries to help you, they just won't be the standard C headers.

Answer (score 0):

As taskinoor mentions, Wikipedia provides an excellent reference about what is included in [stdio.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdio.h).

As for what's possible without stdio.h, pretty much everything that is possible with it, although you will have to work a lot harder for certain things.  If you want to use files, for instance, you will have to define your own abstraction of a file, and your own interface for working with it.  If you want to read input from the keyboard then instead of calling `scanf()` you'll have to use assembly code to call a BIOS interrupt.

Such is the nature of programming an OS.  None of these higher-level constructs exist until you define them and the API for working with them.  You need to start with the smallest basic pieces of functionality, and start grouping them together to create increasingly more useful and complex constructs.